# Storing Encrypted data in client

Tags: javascript, encryption

We have a mobile client application which stores data in localstorage for offline use. The new GDPR requirements have to mandate us to encrypt the data we store in the client.

We used Stanford's sjlc.js package to encrypt the information using AES 128 before storing them in Local Storage. We did a brief performance test and it looks fine.

But the encrypted string is like below.

> {"iv":"C8aBp2GjvPiZHCRtCPu+hg==","v":1,"iter":10000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"duWxiMbE8TM=","ct":"cC4P/pMVozDpmnD/XzW2oif9GId8ZXCo7j/kP6QGlaT8C5pO09SBy6u6DneQz/AdeSQFtG9Ng05i0tASr8RcfNRYQGOFa17I7TI5xVSnd8L7322yihqxhsBbmBFSR0xesAEYmJcoIgPp1/MB+oXzm/pn0pzl0AfZNd8dTHrN+Wa9vcg107+2rVWY7K77BL1j7knRApU....................

We have to pass the whole string back to decrypt.

As you can see it contains the salt as well. Does that defeat the purpose?

Comment: You might want to also ask this over at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The salt is (likely) used by a KDF to derive the key from a password.  Storing this is not a security risk.  How you store the password is definitely important.  Is this data also encrypted client side?

Comment: Thanks @LukeJoshuaPark (and Paulpro for joke) . This is not password but data encryption. The above encrypted string (in yellow) will be stored in the browsers of mobile devices. If someone get hold of the devise, he/she should not be able to decrypt it.